# Sorting csv file alphabetically

Tags: python, csv, math, alphabetical

My whole code currently looks like this.

```
import random   
import time     
import operator
import sys


Class = 0
print("Welcome to the 10 question maths quiz!")          
time.sleep(1)                                            
firstname = input("Please enter your first name.\n")     
time.sleep(1) 
secondname = input("Please enter your second name.\n")   
time.sleep(1)
Class = int(input("What class are you in?\n"))

while Class <1 or Class >3:
    Class = int(input("What class are you in?\n"))

input("Press enter to start the quiz.\n")                

Question = 1
Score = 0

while Question <11:
    Num1 = random.randint(5,15)
    Num2 = random.randint(5,15)
    Ops = {'+':operator.add,
           '-':operator.sub,
           'x':operator.mul,}
    Operation = random.choice(list(Ops.keys()))

    print("Question",Question)
    print(Num1, Operation, Num2)
user_input = int(input())
if Operation == "+":
    answer = (Num1+Num2)
elif Operation == "x":
    answer = (Num1*Num2)
elif Operation == "-":
    answer = (Num1-Num2)
if user_input == answer:
    print("Well done!\n")
    Score = Score + 1
    Question = Question + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect, the answer was", answer,"\n")
    Question = Question + 1

print("You have scored a total of",Score)

if Class == 1:
    myFile = open("Class1test.csv", "a")
    myFile.write(str(firstname))
    myFile.write(" ")
    myFile.write(str(secondname))
    myFile.write(",")
    myFile.write(str(Score))
    myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()

if Class == 2:
    myFile = open("Class2test.csv", "a")
    myFile.write(str(firstname))
    myFile.write(" ")
    myFile.write(str(secondname))
    myFile.write(",")
    myFile.write(str(Score))
    myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()

if Class == 3:
    myFile = open("Class3test.csv", "a")
    myFile.write(str(firstname))
    myFile.write(" ")
    myFile.write(str(secondname))
    myFile.write(",")
    myFile.write(str(Score))
    myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()
```

I am having a lot of issuies regarding csv files as I cant understand how im supposed to display all participants of the quiz in alphabetical order, Highest to lowest score and average.

Please help!!! thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: For example ( '|' meaning new line in csv file), Sean Johnson,4|Adam Carey,6|James Holmes,2|Sacha Stock,8. I need these to be sorted by alphabetical order (names - A-Z), sorted by highest score to lowest score (0-10) and i'm not worried about average as much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
myFile = open('Class{}test.csv'.format(str(Class)), "a")
myFile.write(str(firstname))
myFile.write(" ")
myFile.write(str(secondname))
myFile.write(",")
myFile.write(str(Score))
myFile.write("\n")
myFile.close()
```

instead of those ifs...

And then have a look at this here how to handle csv files in python

[Python CSV-Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

And when you are done creating the csv file use Excel to sort the it and calculate your avg stuff.

ATTENTION: You are using and obsolete delimiter (','). Please use ';' instead to separat columns.

If you really have to use ',' as delimiter, you still can open this file in excel. There is a way "standard" way to change this for tools like excel and co.

Just add 
`sep=,`
as your first row (=separator)

Regards,
Rainer

Comment: Thanks. I've added the csv function and it seems to work.

Comment: Please mark as solved if it worked. And another hint, if you really need to sort it within the csv, please have a look at http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb#Analyze-Data